# How to convert boolean true or false into 1 Or 0 in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {
  return function() {
    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
        var jsonString = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        var jsonObject = (new Function("return " + jsonString))();
        var exportVal = jsonObject.exportValue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is javascript code.it returns true and false value but i want to print  1 and 0.How to solve this problem,please help me.

```
function getReadyStateHandler(xmlHttpRequest) {
    return function() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
                var jsonString = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
                var jsonObject = (new Function("return " + jsonString))();

                var accountid = jsonObject.accountid;

                var exportVal = +jsonObject.exportValue;

                if (accountid.length > 0) {

                    dispTable(accountid, exportVal);

                } 


        }
    };
}

function dispTable(accountid,exportVal) {

    $("#tbl tbody tr").eq(0).remove(); 

    for (var i = 0; i < accountid.length; i++) {
        var temp = parseInt(i) + 1;
        $('#tbl > tbody:last')
                .append(
                        '<tr>' + "<td class='numeric'>"+ temp+ "</td>"
                                + "<td class='numeric'>"+ accountid[i]+ "</td>"
                                + "<td class='numeric'>"+ exportVal[i]+ "</td>"
                                + "<td  class='numeric'>"


    }


}
```

This is my new code.in which i  have displayed the table in which value is displayed as true and  false.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `+` sign:

```
var myVar = true;
myVar = +myVar; // 1

myVar = false;
myVar = +myVar; // 0
```

So if your `jsonObject.exportValue` is boolean you can just convert it by:

```
var exportVal = +jsonObject.exportValue;
```

Comment: @pornima what do you mean by undefined? Are you sure you are converting boolean?

Comment: ya sure.it returns true and false but i want 1 and 0.

Comment: @pornima show us full code, what variable is boolean and where you check it. And how you implemented my solution.

Comment: @pornima looking at your code I don't undestand what returns in `jsonObject.exportValue`? Boolean or array? If boolean you should rewrite your code to `+ "<td class='numeric'>"+ exportVal+ "</td>"`, without `[i]` and if array you should make convertion there `+ "<td class='numeric'>"+ (+exportVal[i])+ "</td>"`

Comment: @pornima You are welcome, don't forget to accept answers if they were helpfull

Answer (score 3):

Simply, use `Number` Function

```
var s = false;
alert(Number(s));
```

For your requirement,

```
 var exportVal = Number(jsonObject.exportValue);
```

Comment: I would recommend this over using the plus sign since it's way clearer that you want to convert it to a number.

Comment: I really don't know but this code returns undefined value

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the ternary operator like:

```
var yourreturnValue = result ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: By using this it also returns undefined